# Weird value for counter variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

For some reason I get "6" inside my function here for every div element:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
  $('<div class="e-' + i + '"></div>').appendTo(something).click(function(){
    alert(i);  // <-- it's 6. wtf??
  });
}
```

instead of 1, 2, 3, etc.

The class on the other hand it appears to be correctly set..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem

Comment: This is called the "last one only" problem. Answer below sums it up nicely, and I wrote an article which contains it a while back: http://lynxphp.com/javascript/javascript-immediate-functions/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `for` loop is being executed at page load time. The alert only fires when there's a click event which is happening after the for loop has finished. Hence the value of `i` is now 6.

1) Page loads, `for` loop does its stuff...

2) Sometime later a click event is fired. the value of `i` at this time is 6 because the `for`loop has already completed.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you need to create a closure to capture the **value** of `i` at the time you bind the click function.

Try this:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
  $('<div class="e-' + i + '"></div>')
    .appendTo(something)
    .click(function(value)
    { 
      return function() { alert(value) };
    }(i));
}
```

Comment: Why not use an anonymous function? It looks better.

Comment: also the `var fn` inside the loop is misleading as there is no block scope in js.

Comment: Cool, didn't know about the lack of block scope. Either way, my unedited answer works fine.

Comment: Eww!  I prefer to do it cleaner still: `for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){createWidget(i);}` and move the entire jQuery statement into `createWidget` or whatever.  Why create an anonymous function every iteration?

Comment: Why create an anonymous function every iteration? You do that to capture the value of `i` each time. That's what a closure does.